# Map Partition Iterator return

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can anyone help in accepting the returning Iterator listWords() method to mapPartitions.

```
object MapPartitionExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf= new SparkConf().setAppName("MapPartitionExample").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc= new SparkContext(conf)

    val input:RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(List("ABC","DEF","GHU","YHG"))

    val x= input.mapPartitions(word => listWords(word))


  }

  def listWords(words: Iterator[String]) : util.Iterator[String] = {

    val arrList = new util.ArrayList[String]()
    while( words.hasNext ) {
      arrList.add( words.next())
    }
    return arrList.iterator()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Return type of the function used in `mapPartitions` should be `scala.collection.Iterator`, not `java.util.Iterator`. I don't see much point of your current code, but you can use Scala mutable collections:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

def listWords(words: Iterator[String]) : Iterator[String] = {
  val arr = ArrayBuffer[String]()
  while( words.hasNext ) {
    arr += words.next()
  }
  arr.toIterator
}
```

Personally I'd just `map`:

```
def listWords(words: Iterator[String])  : Iterator[String] = {
   // Some init code
   words.map(someFunction)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Iterable[NotInferU]` is expected but you are returning `java.util.Iterator[String]`

You would need to convert the `java.util.Iterator` to `scala Iterator` by importing `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` as below

```
  def listWords(words: Iterator[String]) : Iterator[String] = {
    val arrList = new util.ArrayList[String]()
    while( words.hasNext ) {
      arrList.add( words.next())
    }
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    return arrList.toList.iterator
  }
```

Rest of the codes are as it is.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: please accept an answer then whichever you prefer better solution. :)